# AS3 Avoider game tutorial document class

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, class, document

everyone! I'm trying to find an answer to a problem that I've found with the AS3 Avoider Game Tutorial by Michael James Williams, found [here](http://gamedev.michaeljameswilliams.com/2008/10/09/avoider-game-tutorial-3/).
More specifically, I'm stuck on the part where you have to set the "PlayScreen" to a differen Document Class. I right-click on the symbol in the library, select "Properties," and get a pop-up screen that sets up Class, Base Class, linkage...but nothing in there about "Document Class." It doesn't look like the screenshot.

So what do I do, here?? How do I find the document class?

Comment: The document class is set up in the properties panel when you have nothing selected (where the stage colour, FPS and size are).

Comment: That much I've found out already. But how do I attach a different document class to another object/symbol, like my intended gameplay screen?

Comment: Use `Linkage Identifier` name. put it same as of your document class.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you should have declared AvoiderGame.as as your document class, originally. That's the instruction in the first section of the tutorial under 'Making an Enemy.'
This instruction also tells you **how** to declare a document class.

Now, in section 3, you're instructed to create a new class that will become the document class instead of AvoiderGame.as.  It just happens that you're asked to name this class 'DocumentClass.as' But you MAKE it your document class (which, of, course, is the point-of-entry into the game) in the same way as before: by putting it's name -- DocumentClass -- into the document class box in the Properties panel.